# Headphones do not work when unplugged and plugged back in

Tags: windows-10, laptop, dell-inspiron, headphones

When I connect my headphone jack (Sony WH-1000XM2) to my laptop (Dell Inspiron 5480 running Windows 10) upon startup, my headphones work perfectly, but when I unplug the jack and plug it back in, audio plays through my laptop speakers; it doesn't recognize my headphones. What can I do to stop this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem with Dell-XPS and Windows 10. When I restart the computer with the headphones plugged in, they are detected and work OK. But when I unplug them and re-plug them, they do not work - sound comes through the speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Got it fixed. Had to enable Waves MaxxAudio on startup in task manager
Edit 2: Even if it's stopped from prompting every time you insert the headphone jack, it still works.
[image: Image of startup for waves maxxaudio in task manager]

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem for me too.